# Error while creating new role assignment in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

For a given Azure subscription I want to assign custom role to Service Principal. In order to achieve this, I first check if the custom role definition exists in the subscription. If the role does not exists I update the role definition's assignable scope to include this subscription. I am facing 'RoleDefinitionDoesNotExist' error intermittently when I try to assign role. How do I fix this?

My code:

```
$roleDef = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Name $azureRmRole
if($roleDef -eq $null)
{
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $prodSubscription
    #Role definition exists in $prodSubscription
    $newRole = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Name $azureRmRole
    #$scope = '/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
    $newRole.AssignableScopes.Add($scope)
    $def = Set-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $newRole
    # I have verified that role definition is updated
}

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName $azureRmRole -ObjectId $SPNid -Scope $scope
```

Error:

> New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The specified role definition with ID 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist.
>   At C:\Untitled1.ps1:71 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName $azureRmRole -ObjectId  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleAssignment], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand

Comment: Hi, could you find your custom role on Azure Portal? You could use [`New-AzureRmRoleDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroledefinition?view=azurermps-4.3.1) to create a custom role.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes, I am able to find custom role on Azure Portal.

Comment: `$azureRmRole` the vaule is your custom Name. In my example, the name is `Virtual Machine Power Manager`, do you sure it exist?

Comment: What is weird is, even though I get this exception. I am able to see role assignment done on Azure Portal.

Comment: For test,  could you assign role for your service principal on Portal? I test in my lab, I could.

Comment: Yes, I am able to assign role for service principal on portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154651/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-ramana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your custom role like below:

```
{
  "Name": "Virtual Machine Power Manager",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Can monitor, stop, start and restart v2 ARM virtual machines.",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Storage/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Network/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/powerOff/action",    
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action",
    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
    "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*",
    "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/*",
    "Microsoft.Support/*"
  ],
  "NotActions": [

  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/c25b1c8e-xxxx-1111-abcd-1a12d7012123"
  ]
}
```

According to your description, you role's definition maybe wrong, you had better check it.

If you want to give custom role to a service principal, please try to use the following cmdlet.

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalName "https://shuiweb.azurewebsites.net" `
                          -RoleDefinitionName 'Virtual Machine Power Manager' `
                          -Scope '/subscriptions/*******'
```

[image]

The [blog:AZURE AUTOMATION RUNBOOKS WITH AZURE AD SERVICE PRINCIPALS AND CUSTOM RBAC ROLES](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/tag/custom-role/) will be helpful.